# ORA-01502: index or partition of such index is in usable state problem

Tags: oracle-11g, bulkcopy

I have a table in my Oracle database, where

```
select pkcol, count(*) from myTable group by pkcol having count(*) > 1;
```

yields

```
  PKCOL   COUNT(*)
------- ----------
      1          2
      2          2
```

Trying to remove the duplicate rows

```
delete myTable where pkcol = 1;
```

Yields:

> ORA-01502: index 'MYTABLE.PK_MT' or partition of such index is in
>   usable state.

I'm using Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy to fill the table.

As far as I understand documentation [from Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E10927_01/featADO20.htm#BABBFCJJ) PRIMARY KEY constraints had to be checked.

Obviously they are not checked, as I found by doing the same bulkcopy two times in succession which ended in duplicates in all row.

Now I'm only using it after deleting all rows and I'm using a table with a similar primary key as source. As result I expect no problems.

But embedded deep inside my MS Build scripts, I end up with just 2 duplicates out of 2210 rows.

I guess that ignoring the primary key in the first place is a clear bug. No Bulkcopy should be allowed to ignore primary key constraints.

**Edit:**

Meanwhile I found, that the 2 conflicting rows where normally inserted by some script before bulkcopy was called. The problem reduces to my known problem, that bulkcopy doesn't check primary keys here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation you link to](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E10927_01/featADO20.htm#BABBFCJJ):

> UNIQUE constraints are verified when indexes are rebuilt at the end of
>   the load. The index is left in an Index Unusable state if it violates
>   a UNIQUE constraint.

They way I read it, the same applies to `PRIMARY KEY` constraints though the wording is a little ambiguous. You might not like this behaviour, but it is not "a bug" as it is behaving as designed - and there are [other ways](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:8806498660292) of ending up with this sort of 'broken' constraint.

See [this OTN post](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1080639&tstart=690) for more information and an approach that might work better for you using pl/sql and `forall ... save exceptions`.

Comment: Perhaps I misinterpreted the preceding sentence: During an Oracle bulk copy, the following constraints are automatically enabled by default:NOT NULL, UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY (unique-constraints on not-null columns). The problem is that Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy contrary to Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy has no BulkCopyOption CheckConstraints, which makes it difficult to use.

Comment: Yes it is a slightly odd definition of "enabled" isn't it :)

Answer (score 13):

Faced a similar issue.

If you just need to get rid of the error, do:

```
SELECT 'ALTER INDEX '||OWNER||'.'||INDEX_NAME||' REBUILD;'
FROM DBA_INDEXES
WHERE STATUS = 'UNUSABLE';
```

This will output `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD;` statements for all "unusable" indexes. Run them, so that the indexes can be "usable" again.

Answer (score 0):

A short extension to Frosty Z's answer above. If you are not SYSDBA but you are experiencing the same problem within **your own** schema, you can use the following code:

```
SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ' || INDEX_NAME || ' REBUILD;'
  FROM USER_INDEXES
  WHERE STATUS = 'UNUSABLE';
```

Tested with Oracle XE 18c and SQL*Plus 18.4.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the indexes folder and find the index file that gives you the error in your case MYTABLE.PK_MT, then click on Actions -> Rebuild.
That worked for me.